# which cast should be used with a template class parameter, dynamic_cast or reinterpet_cast?

Tags: c++

Could someone please help me?

As far as I know, reinterpet_cast should be avoided at all cost, because it is dangerous. However in my current situation it is the only cast that is working. Normally I would use dynamic_cast, because of inheritence, but the template class specialization does not let me to use dynamic_cast.

In the current situation, my program looks like this.

```
class Object {
public:
  virtual ~Object() = default;
};

template<typename SenderType, typename ...ArgumentType>
class EventCallback : public Object {
public:
  typedef void(SenderType::*Callback)(ArgumentType...);

  EventCallback(Callback callback, SenderType *sender)
    : m_callback{ callback }, m_sender{ sender } {
  }

  virtual ~EventCallback() = default;

  void operator()(ArgumentType ...args) {
    (m_sender->*m_callback)(args...);
  }
private:
  Callback m_callback;
  SenderType *m_sender;
};

template<typename SenderType, typename ...ArgumentType>
class Event : public Object {
public:
  virtual ~Event() = default;

  void operator+=(EventCallback<SenderType, ArgumentType...> callback) {
    m_callbacks.emplace_back(callback);
  }

  void operator()(ArgumentType ...args) {
    for (auto callback : m_callbacks) {
      callback(args...);
    }
  }

  private:
    std::vector<EventCallback<SenderType, ArgumentType...>> m_callbacks;
};    

class ApplicationView : public Object {
public:
  Event<Object> Activated;
  void Activate() {
    // activation logic ...
    Activated();
  }
};


class Application : public Object {
public:
  Application() {
    auto onViewActivated = EventCallback<Application>{&Application::OnViewActivated, this };
    m_view.Activated += reinterpret_cast<EventCallback<Object>&>(onViewActivated);
    m_view.Activate();
  }
  void OnViewActivated() {
  }
};
```

If I modify the above code to dynamic_cast, I get bad dynamic_cast exception. If I use reinterpet_cast, my code runs just fine.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'd disagree with avoiding reinterpret_cast at all cost - reinterpret_cast can be a bit of a cast of last resort, but there are definitely times when you have to use it.

Comment: Does not compile.  Missing `Object` and `Event`.

Comment: This is just a code segment. Object and Event are declared.

Comment: `Event<Application>` does not derive from `Event<Object>`.  If it is possible to convert the former to the latter, you should write your own conversion operator.  It is a coincidence that `reinterpret_cast` works, and it may silently stop working tomorrow.

Comment: Neither reinterpret_cast nor dynamic_cast (nor any other cast) should be necessary here.

Comment: Don't use either form of cast. Get the types right to begin with. Whatever framework this is ought to come with documentation and examples to show you how to make this work.

Comment: I added the complete code here. I started to compose an engine for learning purpose that's why I'm asking. I'm a bit stranger with template programming that's why I ended up with casting in the end :(

Comment: I know that in C++ you never use Object class as a base class to every object. It is a java and c# habit. I created this class for debugging and later for error streaming & logging.

Comment: I think `Object` is getting in the way.  I'd use `std::function<void>` (or whatever is appropriate) for the event callbacks.  You'll probably need the `+=` to return a token to unplumb the (via `-=`) the functor.  Boost provides all this functionality, if you don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I thought that boost library became obsolete since C++11

Comment: @RajmundKail Boost keeps moving forward, think of it as a trial library (and extras) that might make it into the next standard (or not).

Comment: @DrewDormann is correct. Google ‘covariance’ and ‘contravariance’ for a primer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an answer to the questions asked, so my apologies to Rajmund, and I realize that this "answer" will likely be downvoted because of it.

I'm trying to show how to get rid of having the common `Object` class, and avoid using casts altogether.  Too long to show in a comment, and code snippets do not format well in a comment anyway.

Should compile and run.  I used C++17.  I added some placeholder code, which was assumed in Rajmund's code.  I added `cout` to show what is happening.

I do not normally write templates, so I'm expected that the template code could be made nicer.  In particular, it could be nice if the dependent code could do `Event<void()>` instead of `Event<function<void()>>` ... I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.

```
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using std::function;
using std::vector;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

template<typename F>
class Event
{
public:
  void operator+=(F callback)
  {
    m_callbacks.emplace_back(callback);
  }

  template <typename ...ArgumentTypes>
  void operator()(ArgumentTypes ...args)
  {
    // Need a copy, in case a callback adds more callbacks, or removes itself.
    // (I assume callbacks removing themselves, like C#, will be added.)
    auto temp_callbacks = m_callbacks;
    cout << "Event callback list has " << m_callbacks.size() << endl;
    for (auto callback : temp_callbacks)
    {
      cout << "Calling Event callback..." << endl;
      callback(args...);
    }
  }

private:
  vector<F> m_callbacks;
};

class ApplicationView final
{
public:
  Event<function<void()>> Activated;
  void Activate()
  {
    cout << "ApplicationView::Activate has just been called." << endl;
    Activated();
  }
};

class ApplicationViewProvider final
{
public:
  static ApplicationView CreateView();
};

ApplicationView ApplicationViewProvider::CreateView()
{
  return ApplicationView{};
}

class Application final
{
  friend int main();
  ApplicationView m_view;
public:
  Application() :
    m_view{ ApplicationViewProvider::CreateView() }
  {
    auto onViewActivated = [this]() { this->OnViewActivated(); };
    m_view.Activated += onViewActivated;
    m_view.Activate();
  }

  void OnViewActivated()
  {
    cout << "HURRAY! Application::OnViewActivated has been notified." << endl;
  }
};

int main()
{
  cout << "Making Application\n + hooks up OnViewActivated callback\n + calls view's Activate" << endl;
  Application application;
  cout << "\nCalling the view's Activate again, in main" << endl;
  application.m_view.Activate();
}
```

Comment: I like the way you made main function friend of Application class. I've never thought about that. Thanks Eljay :)